# Merging 2 data frames without changing associated values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge, jupyter-notebook

I currently have 2 datasets
1 = Drugs prescribed per hospital
2 = Crimes committed

I have been able to assign the located hospital ID to the various crimes so therefore I can identify which hospital is closer.

What I really would like to do is to assign the amount of drugs prescribed using the count_values method to the hospital ID in the Crime data so that I can then plot a scatter matrix of where the crimes took place and the total quantity of drugs prescribed from the closest hospital.

I have tried using the following

```
df = Crimes.merge(hosp[['hosp no', 'Total Quantity']], 
left_on='hosp_no', right_on='hosp no').drop('hosp no', 1)
df
```

However when I use the above code the associated Hosp ID to the crime changes and I don't want it too!!

I am new to jupyter notebook so I would be most grateful for any help!!
Thank you in advance

Crimes df

```
ID    Type         Hosp No    
 0   Anti-Social     222
```

Hosp df

```
Hosp no     Total Quantity   Drug name
222         1000         Paracetamol
```

So basically Hosp 222 has prescribed 1000 Paracetamol drugs how can I assign the number 1000 to the Crime df where Hosp No = 222 to look like this:
Crimes df

```
ID    Type         Hosp No  Total Quantity  
 0   Anti-Social     222       1000
```

Comment: Its difficult to visualize your problem without some code. Pl post the sample dataframe

Comment: @Vaishali i have updated my answer, hope that helps

Comment: There is no hosp no on Hosp df and what is Total Drugs Prescribed?

Comment: @Vaishali Sorry - hope that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns you are merging on share the same name, you don't need on parameter. Since you need column added to crime, we can use parameter how = left

```
Crimes = Crimes.merge(Hosp[['Hosp No', 'Total Quantity']], how = 'left')

    ID  Type        Hosp No Total Quantity
0   0   Anti-Social 222     1000
```

Let me know if this is the desired output or you need anything else

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It is didn't change the crime data set